# Firewall rules are not working as expected

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, firewall, ftp

I have to setup firewall rules for my onboard network(for list of device which are connected via `eth0` interface) during boot up of Linux device.

By default FTP access over `eth0` should be disabled.

Then read configuration file (`conf.xml`) which contains ipaddress or URL or port those are only allowed to do communication means only whitelisted devices can do communication.

I have done it in following way but it not works as expected

For example. enabled FTP access for a Specific IP mentioned in configuration file (`conf.xml`) using below command

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.10.10.10 --dport 21 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s 10.10.10.10 --dport 21 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

then added below two lines at the end of script for Default - Disabled `eth0` communication using

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j DROP
```

But i see `eth0` communication is permanently disabled and it even not allow ipaddress `10.10.10.10` to access FTP server.

Answer (score 0):

Whitelisting FTP for particular host in your sample contains a typo (probably). Allowing incoming traffic (rule `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.10.10.10 --dport 21 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT`) seems ok if you intend to allow connection from host 10.10.10.10 to some FTP daemon at your machine. The second rule (`iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s 10.10.10.10 --dport 21 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT`) should probably allow destination (not source) host (it should state `-d` instead of `-s`).

Just to mention... The last rule in your chain, `iptables -A ... -j DROP` means that all communication (not matching the previous rules) is disabled, not only FTP.